# Showing in third line local variable L is assigned but never used

Tags: python

```
def create(s):
    enum=" "
    L=range(len(s)-1)
    for n in 1:
        if s[n]==s[n+1]:
            enum+=s[n].upper()
        else:
            enum+=s[n]
        return enum
    print(create("Excellence"))
```

Comment: pls paste the code with corect indentation

Comment: The message is correct. You assign a value to `L` but never use it. Did you mean to write `for n in L:` on the next line?

Comment: The `for n in 1:` loop is weird.  Did you mean to type `L` there?  Even if you did, I think it would be more nearly idiomatic to use `for n in range(len(s) - 1):`.

Answer (score 1):

The warning is indeed correct.

You assign a value to `L` in `L = range(len(s) - 1)` and you never access it in your code again.

`L` has to be used somewhere for the warning to go away.